# Using $_POST for longer than 1 page

Tags: php, html, post, web

I am working on a website where the first page asks you to type in your name.

I want to use the `$_POST['']` to display their name for more than just the next page after the input.
How can I make it remember the `$_POST['']`?

Comment: cookies, embed in hidden form fields, server-side sessions. Lots of options. Pick one and go with it.

Answer (score 1):

Put the name in a session variable:

```
$_SESSION['name']="myName";
```

For complete session reference see http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Answer (score 1):

USE  [Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).In your First page make it like bellow

```
<?
session_start()

$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'] ;

//your rest of codes 


?>
```

and other pageS

```
<?
session_start()

echo  $_SESSION['name'];

//your rest of codes 


?>
```

Comment: But how can I make the user set whats in the session. So if he types in John. The $_POST become John?

Comment: session works depending  on the browser active duration.When user enter john sessions catch the "john" for other pages for later use.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at PHP Sessions:

[PHP Sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)

Note: if its just names you are storing thats cool, if you start to store more private information you will want to look at using sessions in combination with database persistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cookies` or `sessions`

**Using Sessions:**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['KeyName'] = $_POST['HTMLInputName'];
$_SESSION['AnotherKey'] = $_POST['AnotherHTMLInputName'];
```

Then throughout your other pages:

```
session_start(); 
echo $_SESSION['KeyName'];
```

Sessions are useful but you should make modifications to your php.ini so sessions are retained for longer.

**Option 2:**

Using cookies:

```
setcookie("CookieName", $_POST['InputName']);
```

Then on other pages:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['CookieName'])){ echo $_COOKIE['CookieName']; }
```